# Clear Signature in Signature Pad

Tags: javascript, jquery, digital-signature

I'm looking to clear the signature pad field after clicking the clear button. You can see my code below. Something is not right.

```
 buttons: [
    {
        text: "Clear",
        click: function() {
            // $('#box-1').dialog('close');return false;
            $("#box-1").addClass("clearButton");
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
$("#box-1").addClass("clearButton");
});
```